# Installation of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, iso

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 without success. I followed all the suggestions listed regarding taking care of the integrity of the data and the proper way to burn the Ubuntu ISO.

All cases end with an image out of sync that makes it impossible to continue the installation. Any idea about what is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error show?

So the basic question here is; I cannot install Ubuntu. Firstly, perhaps think of installing 13.04 as the latest version, unless you're definitely after that LTS feel. I am making the assumption this is a desktop PC. The specs are correct for this? You're not using a 64BIT for a 32BIT machine?

Please make sure the download is correct: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I think this chat forum will be more useful than me however, so enjoy the link!http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980567